# How to set permanent static IP for Android 10 for the ethernet Over PCIE Connection?

Tags: javascript, java, android, linux-device-driver, lineageos

I am having jetson AGX Board with the Ethernet PCIE Connection and Installed Android 10 with Lineage 17.1-OS and I have Loaded the Fir_Driver Module. Once,the module has been loaded the ethernet node (interface) will be created. If I set the Static IP for that node and trying to make it up and down the IP is getting lost its not persistant.

How I can set the permanent static IP for the Ethernet node over PCIE Connection, which retains the persistant IP when I make it UP and DOWN also?

Please, help me over to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Chaithra

Comment: Why do you want a static IP address? What do you expect to do with this device?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Community,  Once I have been loaded the fir_driver module the eth1 node will be created and using the following command I set the Ip for it "$ ifconfig eth1 5.5.5.6 up" after issuing the command the particular mentioned IP is assigned to the eth1 and making it down using following command "$ ifconfig eth1 down" and Making it Up using command "$ ifconfig eth1 up",this case I am checking validate the particular given IP is persistent or not.  In this Case I am facing IP is Wavering. once the "eth1" is up. please, help me over to resolve this issue

Comment: Can't you change it to static in the Android settings for the network connection? Another alternative would be to configure your DHCP server to reserve a fixed IP address for the MAC address so it always gets the same one.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott, In my system I can't able to give a direct dhcp commands to make it disable, If I tried to issue the direct dhcp commands its throwing the error like "inaccessable or not found". How I can add dhcp utility to my Android device?

Comment: On my phone, I go to 'Settings' -> 'Network & Internet' -> 'Internet'. I don't have an Ethernet connection, but I press the gear icon for the Wi-Fi connection I am using to go to the 'Network details' dialog for that connection. Then I press the pencil icon to edit the details. Then expand the 'Advanced options' section. Then under 'IP settings' it is possible to choose between 'DHCP' or 'Static'. Selecting 'Static' allows the IP address, gateway, network prefix length, and DNS server addresses to be configured.

Comment: Hi, In the Issue that I have Mentioned, the DHCP not come into picture. Its Completely Statically communication establishment, I am able to set the static IP but once I made it DOWN and UP I can't able to see the IP that I have provided

Comment: Hi, In the Issue that I have Mentioned, the DHCP not come into picture. Its Completely Statically communication establishment, I am able to set the static IP but once I made it DOWN and UP I can't able to see the IP that I have provided

Comment: Hi,
@Ian Abbott in this part I am Loading the Driver that Creates one interface node with no dynamic IP Address so DHCP not Came into picture, I can only able to set the static IP for that but its not persistent